# Github Pages Api shows "not found" on get request

Tags: git, github, get, github-pages, github-api

I'm trying to create a page that's going to fetch a list of repositories on Github, then check whether these repositories have Github pages on them, and then create a list based on that info.

The problem is, when I'm trying to fetch Github pages for a repo it always returns "Not found". Say I've got a repo named "nato". Then, according to the docs:

`https://api.github.com/repos/s3fs/nato/pages`

This doesn't work. What could cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that [this call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/pages/#get-a-github-pages-site)  `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pages` requires admin or write access on the repository (authenticated request). One way to check if repository has github pages activated is checking `has_pages` field when you get the repo information :

https://api.github.com/repos/s3fs/nato

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/s3fs/nato" | jq '.has_pages'
```

Output: `true`

While the following repo hasn't github pages activated :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping" | jq '.has_pages'
```

Output: `false`